# test()-function in python? Book "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decided to look a bit into python. I found [this book](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/) began to read it and did some exercises from it. Now I'm stuck at chapter 6, exactly [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/ch06.html#the-for-loop-revisited).
Sorry for my newbie question but where comes this test()-function from?

```
def mysum(xs):
    """ Sum all the numbers in the list xs, and return the total. """
    running_total = 0
    for x in xs:
        running_total = running_total + x
    return running_total

#add tests like these to your test suite ...
test(mysum([1, 2, 3, 4]), 10)
test(mysum([1.25, 2.5, 1.75]), 5.5)
test(mysum([1, -2, 3]), 2)
test(mysum([ ]), 0)
test(mysum(range(11)), 55)    # Remember that 11 is not in the list that range generates.
```

I can't seem to find it and its never mentioned earlier in the book. I only found a module named test. Now I'm kind of confused, am I missing something? There is also a version of this book for Python 2.x which does not use this function in Chapter 6....
Please enlighten a newbie and sorry again for this weird question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in [Section 6.7](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e-rle/fruitful_functions.html#unit-testing) of the linked chapter.

```
def test(actual, expected):
    """ Compare the actual to the expected value,
        and print a suitable message.
    """
    import sys
    linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno   # get the caller's line number.
    if (expected == actual):
        msg = "Test on line {0} passed.".format(linenum)
    else:
        msg = ("Test on line {0} failed. Expected '{1}', but got '{2}'."
                                     . format(linenum, expected, actual))
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Ok. This is not present in the version I was reading. Compare: [Normal](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/index.html) and [RLE Edition](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e-rle/index.html) Argh.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue in Chapter 12 [Dictionaries].  Here's another workaround.

```
def test(expression1, expression2):
    if expression1 == expression2:
        return 'Pass'
    else:
        return 'Fail'
```

This will work for all the expressions you listed as well as the ones listed in Chapter 12 [Dictionaries], specifically Exercise 2.